# Why did I get a "SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call"?

Tags: python, syntax-error, variable-assignment

> **Disclaimer:** *There are many questions asked on Stack Overflow regarding the error message `SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call` in Python. This question provides resources on this error and also may help reviewers find the correct duplicates. This question should **not, itself**, be used as the target.*

The error message

> SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

is produced by all of the following examples:

```
foo() = 3
```

```
mydict = {}
mydict('key') = 3
```

```
for i() in [1, 2, 3]: pass
```

```
[x for int(x) in '123']
```

```
with open('file.txt') as my_file(): pass
```

Why is this syntax not valid, and what code should I write instead?

Comment: "still need to be questions" That's what I'm trying to do with the "But what does that actually mean? What can we assign to, and why is syntax like foo() = 3 not valid? How can I figure out the right code to do what I want, depending on what the context (the actual foo function)?" part, and that's what I answered in my answer. I'd be happy to discuss this more on Meta.

Comment: I don't expect the actual people who really write `foo()=3` and expect something meaningful to happen, to find their case here.

Comment: The question is not for **them** to find the case here. The question is for **duplicate-question voters** to find the case here.

Comment: This asks multiple questions. Ask 1.

Comment: @philipxy **as I have already explained multiple times**, the purpose of this question is to enable others to find the correct duplicate link for other questions. It **must** ask multiple questions because **the entire point** is that there are multiple questions that the OP might have in mind, and the goal is to find the answer that **best matches** that question. This is difficult to do from the search. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418516/.

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: "enable others to find the correct duplicate link for other questions" That's not what questions are supposed to do. You can draft such a list on your computer or create a shared one like the dupe list from the Python chat room, but the main site is certainly not the place for this.

Comment: Maybe you could ask something like, process for debugging xxx error. Although that could be considered unfocused & unresearched. That is a problem with self-answering. Asking about a bug/error should have a [mre] including explanation giving expectations & why those expectations are held justified by reference to authoritative documentation, while asking about composing the overall goal should not include misunderstood/meaningless code. But people ask bad questions instead dumping bad code & no reasoning, just asking for a rewrite of a reference/manual & bespoke tutorial that reads their mind.

Comment: A "process" Q&A per my suggestion might best have an answer that is a branching troubleshooting flowchart, so that it is in fact one answer & doesn't ask more questions. But this Q&A becomes more & more like a [meta] or [softwareengineering.se] post. Which unfortunately it maybe needs to be because of the on-topic & voting structure of SO. Again, not surprising because the problem you are trying to solve is bad questions & they shouldn't be asked so you are trying to supply an answer/response to questions that shouldn't be asked, which doesn't really fit SO. PS Very much admire the goal.

Answer (score 3):

### Why isn't this syntax valid?

### What can we assign to?

Python requires the left-hand side of an assignment - whether it's a plain assignment like `=`, or any kind of *augmented assignment* like `+=` - to *name* what will be assigned. After all, the purpose of assignment is to *make it possible to refer to a value in a specific way*. The rules are fairly complex, because there is a lot of flexibility; but in general, one or more "references" are required. Usually the left-hand side will be a single *name* (i.e., variable), but it could also be:

- recursively, an attribute of some other valid single reference (`foo.bar = 3`)
- recursively, a dict entry, element, or slice of some other valid single reference (`foo['bar'] = 3` where `foo` is a `dict`, or `foo[0] = 3` or `foo[:] = [1,2,3]` where `foo` is a `list)
- an unpacking pattern (there doesn't seem to be official terminology for this, but things like `foo, bar = "hi"`, or `foo, *bar = "example"`)

Function-call syntax does not qualify as any of these. Functions **return values, not variables**, so there is nothing to assign to. `foo() = 3` makes no sense, for the same reason that `2 = 3` (or even `3 = 3`) makes no sense.

---

### What are some common reasons for trying to write code this way?

### What is the corresponding correct approach?

Here are some ways the problem could conceivably come up:

- You simply have the assignment statement the wrong way around. Remember, the *value that you are naming* - whether you compute it here, or use another existing name for it - goes on the **right**, and the *new name you want to use for it* goes on the **left**. See [SyntaxError: "can't assign to function call"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964927).
- You want to use `(` and `)` symbols as part of a variable name. This is simply not allowed. See [SyntaxError: can't assign to function call, while trying to plot a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502443) or [Python writing recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455808).
- You wanted the function to return some kind of "reference" so that you could assign data into a data structure, based on the result of the call. Python does not work this way; the function can only ever give you a *value* back.

If you wanted to assign to a key in a dictionary or element in an array, use code that gives you the *key* or the *index*, **not** the value. See for example [How do I randomly select a variable from a list, and then modify it in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288236). If you wanted to assign to an attribute that was looked up with `getattr`, use `setattr` instead: see [assign a attribute using getattr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847177). PyQt's `.text()` accessor has a corresponding `.setText` mutator: see [Error:Can't assign to function call Python/PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845053).

Pandas is an especially common source of this issue, because there is a lot of functionality that returns some subset of a DataFrame, and it's common to want to assign to those cells. Numpy doesn't generally have this problem because its selection is generally done using slicing, so the syntax supports assignment (Numpy arrays simply have to implement `__setitem__` to accept `slice` objects, and they do).

- You want to use some code to compute a string, and then use the string as a variable name for an assignment. Aside from not working, this is **definitely not how you want to solve the problem**, whatever it is. Use a dict or a list instead. See [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/).
- You have something like `f(x) = 3` because you want to *change `x` in such a way that* `f(x) == 3` becomes true. This is not directly possible; you need to rearrange the equation. If you are simply doing math then this is just a matter of algebra. In general you will need to figure out an inverse function `g` which satisfies `g(f(x)) == x` for all `x` values; then you can do `x = g(3)`. This function may already exist. For example, see ["Can't assign to function call"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652444) - `chr` is the built-in inverse for `ord` (and vice-versa). [Archimedean spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485993) is a similar example with Numpy.
- You want to index into a list, dict, Numpy array, etc. and set the value at that index. In Python, indexing is done with `[]`, not `()`. See [Dictionary syntax error "can't assign to function call"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924150) or [How to have an array of arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438039).
- You have a function defined like `def foo(x, y): pass`, and then you want to *replace the `foo` function* with a different function. This is an advanced usage, but it is necessary for what is called *mocking* when using automated tests for your code. The mistake is in thinking that the parameter list is part of the function name, thus writing something like `foo(x, y) = create_mock()`. The parameter list is not part of the name of `foo` (there might be a parameter list on the right-hand side, because you are calling a function *that returns a function*). The code should just look like `foo = create_mock()` instead. See [Mocking Method Calls In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43941015).
- You are trying to use `as` in either a `with` statement or an `except` statement, and put `()` at the end, like `with f(x) as y():` or `except RuntimeError as e():`. These statements **are a kind of assignment**, and the parentheses are a typo - simply remove them. See [with tf.Session() as session(): ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390732).
- You wanted to do some kind of pre-processing on values that you're iterating over, for example `for f(x) in xs:`. This does not work because a `for` loop **is a kind of assignment**. Instead, get the raw values like `for x in xs:`, and do the preprocessing inside the loop, e.g. `x = f(x)`. See [How do you iterate through each email in your inbox using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983647).
- Similarly, you have the syntax for a list comprehension the wrong way around: `[x for f(x) in xs]`. This should instead be `[f(x) for x in xs]`. See [Iterrows a rolling sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178537).
- You want to enforce that the assigned value will have a specific type. `int(foo) = int('3')` does not make sense; `int` works on *values*, not on variables. (Again, it is a function, and that is how functions work.) Just make sure that the value has the appropriate type: `foo = int('3')` (Of course, this is a silly example; `foo = 3` is better). See [SyntaxError: can't assign to function call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57179955).

Comment: Some of these links are not very good quality. You can help by editing in better reference links, or even by trying to create better-quality canonicals for the specific use cases. (I especially need help cleaning up all the Pandas examples, because I am not a Pandas expert and am not sure what common threads there are between the questions, or how to explain the problem in a generic way.)

Comment: You can also help by going through the [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22can%27t%20assign%20to%20function%20call%22%20%5bpython%5d%20is%3aquestion) to find things that should be redirected or otherwise closed, or identifying any other patterns in the causes of the error.

Comment: I removed (and copied locally) the Pandas links for now, pending a closer evaluation. I think I probably do have enough knowledge to go through them and figure out if there are specific patterns. In the best case, it should be possible to write a canonical explaining technique for avoiding the problem.